# Double run-length encoding

Tags: code-golf, string, encoding

Everyone knows what run-length encoding is. It has been the subject of many code-golf challenges already. We'll be looking at a certain variation.

#### Example

```
Normal: 11222222222222222222233333111111111112333322
Run-length: 112(19)3(5)1(11)2333322
```

The number in parentheses specifies the number of times the previous symbol occurred. In the example, only runs of 5 or more characters were encoded. This is because encoding runs of 4 or less doesn't improve the character count.

### Challenge

Write a function/program that implements this variation of run-length encoding, but can also encode runs of two symbols. The runs of two symbols must also be enclosed in parentheses. A group will also be enclosed in parentheses. Your program must accept a string as input, and output the modified string with modifications that shorten the string.

#### Example

```
Normal: 111244411144411144411167676767222222277777222222277777123123123123
Double run-length: 1112((444111)(3))67676767((2(7)7(5))(2))123123123123
```

#### Notes

- `111` was not encoded because encoding it (`1(3)`) is not shorter.
- The string `444111` occurs 3 times so it is encoded.
- `676767` was not encoded because `((67)(4))` is longer than before.
- `222222277777222222277777` was not encoded as `((222222277777)(2))`. Why? Because `222222277777` itself can be reduced to `2(7)7(5)`.
- `123123123123` isn't encoded because your program is supposed to handle runs of two symbols, not three.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins. Tie-breaker is early submission.

---

If I missed anything, or if you are unsure of anything please notify me in the comments.

Comment: But there are 4 `67`s.

Comment: Will we have to handle `441444144414` -> `((4414)(3))`?

Comment: I have fixed it.

Comment: @KennyLau No, you will not. `4414` is technically a series of 4. My wording is just bad.

Comment: Can `111111111` be encoded as `(1)(9)`?

Comment: It should be encoded as `1(9)`, because it's shorter than `(1)(9)`.

Comment: ((4(9)1)(2)) or 4(9)14(9)1?

Comment: The second one. Remember, pick whichever is shorter.

Comment: You might want to add more testcases (hint: they are in my solution)

Comment: Um, `(67(4))` [7 characters] is _definitely_ shorter than `67676767` [8 characters].

Comment: `(67(4))` implies `67777`.

Comment: Yoinks! (I need sleep, apparently.)

Comment: @ppperry I believe that should be `(4(1111))`.

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, 162 bytes

```
+{`((\d)\2*(?!\2)(\d)\3*|\d)(?<1>\1)+
<<$1><$#1>>
<<([^<>]{1,7})><2>>
$1$1
<<([^<>]{1,3})><3>>
$1$1$1
<<([^<>]{1,2})><4>>
$1$1$1$1
}`<<(.)><(\d+)>>
$1($2)
T`<>`()
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K3tgKChcZClcMiooPyFcMikoXGQpXDMqfFxkKSg_PDE-XDEpKwo8PCQxPjwkIzE-Pgo8PChbXjw-XXsxLDd9KT48Mj4-CiQxJDEKPDwoW148Pl17MSwzfSk-PDM-PgokMSQxJDEKPDwoW148Pl17MSwyfSk-PDQ-PgokMSQxJDEkMQp9YDw8KC4pPjwoXGQrKT4-CiQxKCQyKQpUYDw-YCgp&input=MTExMjQ0NDExMTQ0NDExMTQ0NDExMTY3Njc2NzY3MjIyMjIyMjc3Nzc3MjIyMjIyMjc3Nzc3MTIzMTIzMTIzMTIzMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTQ0NDQ0NDQ0MTQ0NDQ0NDQ0MQ)

Comment: If you input `10101010100100100100100`, the output is `((10)(5))0((100)(4))`, yet `((10)(4))((100)(5))` would be one character shorter.

Comment: Do you really have to use such marginal testcases....

Comment: Yes, thats all the fun! :^)

Comment: It's funny how this is the only answer currently here.