# Shortest simple regex matching a binary word

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression, metagolf, search

## Task

Define a *simple regex* as a non-empty regular expression consisting only of

- characters `0` and `1`,
- grouping parentheses `(` and `)`,
- one-or-more repetition quantifier `+`.

Given a non-empty string of `0`s and `1`s, your program should find the shortest simple regex matching the **full** input string. (That is, when matching a simple regex, pretend it’s bookended by `^` and `$`.) If there are multiple shortest regexes, print any or all of them.)

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

## Test cases

```
1 -> 1
00 -> 00 or 0+
010 -> 010
1110 -> 1+0
01010 -> 01010
0101010 -> 0(10)+ or (01)+0
011111 -> 01+
10110110 -> (1+0)+
01100110 -> (0110)+ or (01+0)+
010010010 -> (010)+
111100111 -> 1+001+ or 1+0+1+
00000101010 -> 0+(10)+ or (0+1)+0
1010110001 -> 1(0+1+)+ or (1+0+)+1
```

Comment: You should clarify that you want us to write a program that writes the regex, not write the regex ourself. But this looks interesting.

Comment: In my testing, `01100110` is an interesting case... a naïve algorithm would write `01+0+1+0` or `(0+1+)+0` which aren't optimal.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79529/double-run-length-encoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
hf.x}z:zT1Zy*4"()01+
```

This takes approximately 30 seconds to run, so it needs to be run offline.

Explanation:

```
hf.x}z:zT1Zy*4"()01+
                        Implicit: z is the input string.
              "()01+    "()01+"
            *4          Repeated 4 times
           y            All subsequences in length order
hf                      Output the first one such that
      :zT1              Form all regex matches of z with the candidate string
    }z                  Check if the input is one of the strings
  .x      Z             Discard errors
```

I'm not completely sure that every shortest string is a subsequence of "()01+" * 4, but 4 can be increased to 9 at no byte cost if needed.

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>488</s> 341 bytes

```
s=>[s.replace(/(.)\1+/g,'$1+'),...[...Array(60)].map((_,i)=>`(${(i+4).toString(2).slice(1)})+`),...[...Array(1536)].map((_,i)=>`${i>>10?(i>>8&1)+(i&2?'+':''):''}(${i&1}${i&4?i>>4&1:i&16?'+':''}${i&8?''+(i>>7&1)+(i&64?i>>5&1:i&32?'+':''):''})+${i&512?(i>>8&1)+(i&2?'+':''):''}`)].filter(r=>s.match(`^${r}$`)).sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length)[0]
```

Explanation: Since six regexes can express all possible binary words, and the longest two are nine characters long, it suffices to check those and all shorter regexes. One candidate is obviously the string with "run length encoding" (i.e. all digit runs replaced with appropriate `+`s), but also strings with one set of `()`s need to be checked. I generate 1596 such regexes (this includes duplicates and useless regexes but they'll just be eliminated) and test all 1597 to see which is the shortest match. The generated regexes fall into two types: `\(\d{2,5}\)\+` (60 regexes) and `(\d\+?)?\(\d[\d+]?(\d[\d+]?)?\)(\d\+?)?` (1536 regexes as I avoid generating regexes with both leading and trailing digit).

Comment: @LeakyNun Originally I thought there were 4 regexes of length 9 but this is obviously incorrect so I've clarified my explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

Brute force! Can probably golf the iterator a little.

```
 f=+Yf.x:zjY"^$")Z^"10+()"T1Y
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=+f%3D%2BYf.x%3AzjY%22%5E%24%22%29Z%5E%2210%2B%28%29%22T1Y&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A00%0A010%0A1110%0A01010%0A0101010%0A011111&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 109 bytes

It's the boring brute force approach. Works because no regex ever need be longer than 9 characters (as Neil notes) and no individual character needs to be repeated more than 4 times (trying it with `'01()+'.chars*9` made my CPU unhappy).

```
10.times{|i|('01()+'.chars*4).combination(i).map{|s|begin
/^#{s*''}$/=~$*[0]&&[puts(s*''),exit]
rescue
end}}
```

```bash
$ for word in `grep -Po '^\S+' test_cases.txt`; do nice -n20 ruby sre.rb $word; done
1
0+
010
1+0
01010
0(10)+
01+
(1+0)+
(01+0)+
(010)+
1+0+1+
0+(10)+
1(0+1+)+
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 186 bytes

I'm investigating whether there is an approach to this problem besides brute-forcing, but here is a Python brute-force solution for now.

```python
import re,itertools
def a(b):
 for z in range(10):
  for i in itertools.combinations("01()+"*4,z):
   j=''.join(i)
   try:
    if re.fullmatch(j,b)and len(j)<=len(b):return j
   except:1
```